# Bring interface up even if link is down (no carrier)

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface, networkmanager, netplan

My system is a Dell PowerEdge T140, running Ubuntu 18.04.2.

I have a service that depends on the host's primary IP address, and that service fails to start if that address is not configured on the host.

Is there a way to have `netplan` bring a statically-configured interface up, even if the link for that interface is down at boot time, and keep it up if if the link is lost at any given time?  I haven't been able to do it yet, neither with `NetworkManager` nor with `networkd` as the renderer.

During my testing, I tried to force the network up with `ip link set eno1 up`, but it didn't work.  However, e.g. `ifconfig eno1 192.168.1.1 netmask 0xffffff00` **does work**, and possibly I could use it as a workaround (by doing something like adding that command to `rc.local` and forcing the broken service to restart).

The workaround solution, however, is very ugly, and it uses a tool (`ifconfig`) which is no longer in the default installation, so I'd rather avoid it, and stick to being as close to standard configurations as possible.

Comment: I know that with Debian if you configure a static interface in `/etc/network/interfaces`, NetworkManager won't touch that interface, and you can then configure the IP address on that interface irrespective of the link being up or not. However perhaps Ubuntu is different.

Comment: Related, `ifconfig` replacement is `ip addr`. `command -v ifconfig` and `command -v ip` will tell you which one is available. I miss the old days when `hostname`, `ifconfig`, `cron` and friends worked...

Comment: actually one `ifconfig` command setting an address should be replaced with two commands: `ip addr add ...` + `ip link set ... up`, because the up is implicit in `ifconfig` in such case.

Comment: possible explanation there: [Why is Netplan/Networkd not bringing up a static ethernet interface?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046420/why-is-netplan-networkd-not-bringing-up-a-static-ethernet-interface/1048041#1048041)

Comment: @A.B, yes... I think it is the right explanation.  Thank you for the find (I did a lot of search before asking my question, but maybe not with the correct terms)!  I'll try it as soon as I return home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The boolean property ignore-carrier does the trick.
In your netplan yaml file (typically under /etc/netplan/):

```
     eno1:
        ignore-carrier: true
        addresses:
        - 192.168.1.1/24
        match:
            macaddress: <NIC MAC addr>
        mtu: 1500
        optional: true
        set-name: eno1
```

More details at [Netplan Reference](https://netplan.io/reference/#common-properties-for-physical-device-types)